# How to convert a csv file uploaded to utf-8 encoding using iconv

Tags: php, utf-8, yii2, phpexcel, iconv

i  want to read  the contents of a csv file uploaded and then write back it into the file after converting it to  utf-8 encoding

i found that i can use the following code to convert the encoding 
iconv('hebrew', 'utf-8', $str);

i used following code to read the csv file line by line and write it back after converting . 
The main idea was to  import the csv  by reading line by line but had some issues with hebrew based on encdoing of the file  .

So Used the following code to check if encoding is utf-8 or utf-16le (of windows) and then convert the data accordingly. If data does not match one of those encodings then to use iconv('hebrew', 'utf-8', $str);  but it not working

```
public function actionUpload()
    {
        $params = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
        if($params)
        {
            $data = array();
            $model = new UploadForm();
            $model->uploadFile = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
            $file =  UploadedFile::getInstanceByname('uploadFile');
            $inputFileName = $model->getpath($file,$data);
            //  Read your Excel workbook
            try
            {
                $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName['link']);
                $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                if($inputFileType == 'CSV')
                {   



                    if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($inputFileName['link']), 'UTF-8'))
                    {
                        $objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');
                    }
                    else if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($inputFileName['link']), 'UTF-16le'))
                    {
                      $objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-16le');
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                         $handle = fopen("test.csv", "r+");
                         if ($handle) 
                         {
                           while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
                           {
                             $newLine =  iconv('hebrew', 'utf-8', $line);
                             fwrite($handle , $newLine);
                           }

                           fclose($handle);
                         } 
                         else 
                         {
                            // error opening the file.
                         } 

                        $objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');

                    }


                }
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName['link']);
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName['link'],PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
            }

            //  Get worksheet dimensions
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
            $fileData = array();
            //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
            { 
                //  Read a row of data into an array
                $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                                NULL,
                                                TRUE,
                                                FALSE);
                array_push($fileData,$rowData[0]);
                //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
            }
            return $fileData;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack in PHP documentation comments, to convert hebrew encoding to utf-8

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#49434